# Adding items to an array within an array with php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has an array containing more data stored into one of the keys in the original array.

For example:

```
$array2 = array('some_data');
$array1 = array(
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
'data' => $array2);
```

The array1 can also have multiple occurrences, another words store data for more then one user. How can I add more "data" to the data array within $array1?

I tried doing

```
$array1[0]['data'][] = array('diff_data');
```

but I keep getting errors. Is there a better way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: `$array1['data'][] = 'diff_data';`

Comment: array_push($array1['data'],'diff_data');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new data to

```
$array1['data'][] = 'new data';
```

and you can acces this data like this:

```
echo ($array1['data'][0]);
```

Where 0 is the index of the array2 element.