# How can I add a new array to a item?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add an array to an array item?

I want each item to have an array assigned to it, in this case with a `tags` key. But the following doesn't work as expected:

```
<?php   
function getNews() {
    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM news WHERE active = '1' AND deleted='0'
            ORDER BY date_posted DESC LIMIT ".   
                 (isset($settings['news_limit_index']) 
                        ? $settings['news_limit_index'] : '4');
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    while($data=$result->fetch_assoc()){
         $r_news[] = $data;
         $r_news[]['tags'] = array('one','two','three'); // hardcoded for testing!
    }
    return $r_news; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding items to an array within an array with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679617/adding-items-to-an-array-within-an-array-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not assigning to the same `$r_news` element in these two lines:

```
$r_news[] = $data;
$r_news[]['tags'] = array('one','two','three'); // hardcoded for testing!
```

You add 2 elements with the above code, and the second only has the `tags` key.

One solution: extend `$data` with the `tags` key first, and then add it to your array:

```
$data['tags'] = array('one','two','three');
$r_news[] = $data;
```

Comment: hello, this solution worked for me, and it seems te be the best solution.
Thanx in advance :-)

Comment: If this solution worked for you Please consider marking this answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add both `$data` and tags subarray using an index variable.

```
$i = 0;
while($data=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $r_news[$i] = $data;
    $r_news[$i++]['tags'] = array('one','two','three'); // hardcoded for testing!
}
```